# Swifty way to call a function only once until a var is reset

Tags: ios, swift

In below code scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is called at end of scrolling. Post which i call some function which has API call only if there is no another API called already.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if isReachedBottom && !apiCallInProgress {
        callNextPage()
    }
}

func callNextPage() {
    apiCallInProgress = true
    callAPI {
        self.apiCallInProgress = false
        //success
    }
}
```

Now the above code works fine. But want to know if there is a better(Swifty) way to do the same as here I need to maintain the variable(apiCallInProgress) to do this function apiCallInProgress

Comment: We still need to maintain the variable to check it. Looking if there is a way by not maintaining the variable. Also I am not sure if that is possible at all.

Comment: I think you need to better explain what you mean with swifty  way and non maintainable

Comment: You will need to be clearer on what's you're trying to achieve.  If you want to base an operation on some property of state, you are going to need a way to maintain that state.

Comment: The apiCallInProgree var could be declared and used only in the callNextPage method. You just need to declare it as static. Then just callNextPage() when bottom reached.